# Android Studio 2.0 Cannot launch AVD in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I can successfully launch AVDs for the targets Android 5.1 (Google APIs) and Android 6.0 (Google APIs), both using CPU=x86. However the AVD I create for Android 4.1 (Google APIs) using CPU=arm cannot be launched. When I try to launch it I see a dialog:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

Since two AVDs do work I'm sure ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined. I've also verified that File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location is correct.

I have also run the Android SDK Manager, uninstalled all API 16 items and reinstalled these API 16 items:

```
SDK Platform
Intel x86 Atom System Images
ARM EABI v7a System Image
Google APIs
Sources for Android SDK
```

Within the Android SDK Manager all other libraries and packages are up to date. And I have restarted my Windows 7 computer.

Also note that I am forced to create this API 16 AVD for CPU=arm rather than using CPU=x86 as the Android Virtual Device Manager, when showing available system images, does not show an x86 image for target=Android 4.1 with Google APIs).

Does anyone know what the problem is? Or suggest things I can try to debug this issue?

**Edit from a day after opening this question:** Since I've seen no answer I'm assuming this is another Android Studio bug. I've input this bug report - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207494

Comment: Dont forget to enable virtualization technology also , And install HAXM also id you are using  windows

Comment: This problem only appeared when I updated to Android Studio 2.0. Emulation with and without HAMX worked fine before.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while trying to run ARM based emulator which is of API 16. I got this error when ARM images are downloaded from the android-studio itself( Not using Standalone SDK Manager option under System Settings->Android SDK in android-studio).

I solved this by launching Standalone SDK Manager from android studio. Then open Tools->Manage AVDs from Standalone SDK Manager menu. Here you can find your emulators. I observed that my ARM CPU emulator shows question marks in the columns named Platform,API label,CPU/ABI. Which seems to be some sort bug. Select the Emulator and click on edit. Choose the Target API,CPU/ABI properly and then click ok. 
Now my emulator works perfectly. This solved my problem.

I figured out that updating android-studio caused this problem for me.

Comment: it's still happening... switching back to Genymotion. By the way... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207494